# Displaying Elements with a delay

Tags: android

How to make a delay on displaying elements in android studio i have 2 ImageView

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/a_letter"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="100dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/a_letter"
            />
```

AND

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/b_letter"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="100dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/b_letter"
            />
```

how to make the `ImageView` with the **ID** of `a_letter` load first when the layout is opened then make a 3 seconds delay before the `ImageView` with the **ID** of `b_letter` displayed?

is this a transition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make your image view gone in xml by adding:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/b_letter"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="100dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/b_letter"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

and then use a `Handler`:

```
ImageView bImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.b_letter);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        bImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}, 3000);
```

Comment: I'll just wait for 3 mins to vote this as the BEST answer :) thank you for understanding my situation I'm just a beginner hehe